How to modify the custom layout HTML parent properties in DataTables 2.0?
I am trying to add some custom HTML to the top of my DataTable, but I am noting that the columns DataTables automatically creates for native fields and custom fields do not have the same properties (native: col-md-auto, custom: col-md).
How can I modify the parent classes of custom layouts in DataTables 2.0? I'm trying to avoid a hacky workaround with chaining CSS selectors if possible.
Here we can see the result is that my custom HTML sections are added, but they are set to col-md rather than col-md-auto causing the text to stack at some screensizes


I also want to know how to modify the container's classes so I can set custom flex properties on the columns and have my custom HTML properly vertically aligned. For example if we inspect element and set <div class="col-md"> to be <div class="col-md-auto d-flex align-items-center"> then I can get proper text alignment for my links section. Otherwise they are not vertically aligned
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/2.0.3/css/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/2.0.3/js/dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/2.0.3/js/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.js"></script>


<table id="myDataTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Garrett Winters</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>63</td>
      <td>2011/07/25</td>
      <td>$170,750</td>
    </tr>
    <!-- More rows -->
  </tbody>
</table>


<section id="links" class="" aria-label="Links">
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="#">Test</a>
  <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
</section>

<div id="archived_checkbox_container" class="filter-option d-flex align-items-end">
  <div class="ms-auto form-switch d-flex">
    <input id="show-archived" name="show-archived" type="checkbox" class="form-check-input me-2">
    <label for="show-archived">Archived</label>
  </div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {

  let html_links = $("#links");
  let html_archived_check = $("#archived_checkbox_container");

  $('#myDataTable').DataTable({
    searching: true,
    searchDelay: 500, //(ms) avoid searching on every keystroke

    layout: {
      //random note: for custom layout keys, must start with 'top' or 'bottom'. Probably
      //datatables is parsing for that internally and silently discarding otherwise?
      topStart: "pageLength",
      topMiddleCustom: [html_links],
      topMiddle2Custom: [html_archived_check],
      topEndCustom: "search", //add default search bar *manually* to fix positioning
      topEnd: null //remove the default search bar because it gets positioned wrong
    },
  });
});

It is much easier to understand my question by checking the JSFiddle and inspecting element on the resulting output
https://jsfiddle.net/kq4ws817/2/

Since you are using bootstrap5 you can monkey patch the default behaviour. Add the below to your code after DT is loaded, but before you initialize any datatable. It simply changes the default use of col-md to col-md-auto :
DataTable.ext.renderer.layout.bootstrap = function ( settings, container, items ) {
  var row = $( '<div/>', {
    "class": items.full ?
        'row mt-2 justify-content-md-center' :
        'row mt-2 justify-content-between'
    } )
    .appendTo( container );

    $.each( items, function (key, val) {
      var klass;

      // Apply start / end (left / right when ltr) margins
      if (val.table) {
        klass = 'col-12';
      }
      else if (key === 'start') {
        klass = 'col-md-auto me-auto';
      }
      else if (key === 'end') {
        klass = 'col-md-auto ms-auto';
      }
      else {
        klass = 'col-md-auto'; //<--- HERE
      }

      $( '<div/>', {
        id: val.id || null,
        "class": klass + ' ' + (val.className || '')
      } )
      .append( val.contents )
      .appendTo( row );
    } );
 };

Forked fiddle -> https://jsfiddle.net/qsvnp2o1/
See
https://github.com/DataTables/DataTablesSrc/blob/master/js/integration/dataTables.bootstrap5.js
for details

OR, you could replace CSS-classes in the initComplete callback :
initComplete: function() {
  html_links.parent().addClass('col-md-auto').removeClass('col-md')
  html_archived_check.parent().addClass('col-md-auto').removeClass('col-md')
}

Forked fiddle -> https://jsfiddle.net/z8q7yp4e/
